# How to copy array into bigger array and add zeros into unused space? C++

Tags: c++, arrays

C++

I am making a program that asks the user for a number, sets that number as the size of the first array then asks the user for numbers based off the size. It then asks for another array size and sets that to the second array size. If the second array size is bigger than the first, I need to copy the first into the second and add 0 to unused spaces.

For example, the output should look like:

```
Enter first array size: 3
Enter a number: 45
Enter a number: 54
Enter a number: 65
45 54 65 // First array printed out

Enter second array size: 10
45 54 65 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 // Second array printed out
```

I need help adding 0 to the unused space if the second array is bigger.

Also, I am unsure if how I am copying the array is the best method.

Snippet of code:

```
int *secondArray = new int[secondSize]; // Create array

for(int j = 0; j < secondSize; ++j)
{
    secondArray[j] = firstArray[j]; // Set second array equal to first array

    if (secondSize > firstSize)
    {
        // ?
    }

}
```

Comment: Use a vector (instead of an array) and resize it. Done.

Comment: Did you think about this at all? What are the possibilities? The new size can be bigger, smaller or the same. Write if conditions and for loops that cover each of those and you are done.

Comment: @ZanLynx I already have conditions for the array being smaller or the same. I just needed help on this little part.

Comment: If you have to do it this way, `int *secondArray = new int[secondSize]();` and you're done after copying the first array in.

Comment: Not quite dupes but definitely related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21921931/trouble-copying-contents-of-an-array-into-another-array-getting-weird-numbers

Answer (score 2):

It's this simple (but note `j` replaces `secondSize` in your code)--

```
if (j >= firstSize)
{
    secondArray[j] = 0;
}
```

Edit: see @Fred Larson's comment below about avoiding redundant assignment.  Here is the snappy version:

```
secondArray[j] = (j >= firstSize) ? 0 : firstArray[j];
```

Comment: Wow, I figured it would be something simple. This solved my problem, thank you.

Comment: Note also that the other assignment should be in the `else` of this check.

Comment: Note that the `if` can be removed entirely by initialising `secondArray` upon creation, as `new int[secondSize]{0}` or `new int[secondSize]()`.

Answer (score 1):

Your code snippet copies data from firstArray that doesn't exist if secondSize is bigger than firstSize.

Don't put the if statement inside the loop. That is a time waster.

Try this:

```
size_t i;
if(firstSize < secondSize) {
    for(i=0; i<firstSize; ++i)
        secondArray[i] = firstArray[i];
    for(;i<secondSize; ++i)
        secondArray[i] = 0;
} else {
    for(i=0; i<secondSize; ++i)
        secondArray[i] = firstArray[i];
}
```

Untested, but I am pretty sure that's the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

It would be simpler if instead of dynamically allocated arrays you would use standard class `std::vector`

Here is an example of how the task can be done with using dynamically allocated arrays and with using class `std::vector`. You may choice what you need among two blocks of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cstring>


int main() 
{
    {
        std::cout  << "Enter first array size: ";
        size_t n1 = 0;
        std::cin >> n1;

        int *a1 = new int[n1]();

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
        {
            std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
            std::cin >> a1[i];
        }

        std::cout  << "Enter second array size: ";
        size_t n2 = 0;
        std::cin >> n2;

        int *a2 = new int[n2]();

        std::memcpy( a2, a1, ( n2 < n1 ? n2 : n1 ) * sizeof( int ) );

        for ( size_t i = 0; i < n2; i++ ) std::cout << a2[i] << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;

        delete [] a1;
        delete [] a2;
    }

    {
        std::cout  << "Enter first array size: ";
        std::vector<int>::size_type n1 = 0;
        std::cin >> n1;

        std::vector<int> v1( n1 );

        for ( std::vector<int>::size_type i = 0; i < n1; i++ )
        {
            std::cout << "Enter a number: ";
            std::cin >> v1[i];
        }

        std::cout  << "Enter second array size: ";
        std::vector<int>::size_type n2 = 0;
        std::cin >> n2;

        std::vector<int> v2( v1.begin(), v1.begin() + ( n2 < n1 ? n2 : n1 ) );
        v2.resize( n2 );

        for ( int x : v2 ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using STL vectors, since they'll handle the memory management automatically ([see std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)).  But, if you have to use arrays for whatever reason, I'd recommend something more like the following:

```
int *secondArray = new int[secondSize]; // Create array
    //Initialize secondArray to 0
for(int i = 0; i < secondSize; i++) secondArray[i] = 0;
    //Then use your code
for(int j = 0; j < secondSize; ++j)
{
    secondArray[j] = firstArray[j]; // Set second array equal to first array
}
```

This won't check for the situation where secondSize < firstSize, though.  You might want to add a check before allocating memory, or something similar.

Comment: Your first loop should be `std::fill_n` (or just zeroing it to begin with) and the second should be `std::copy_n`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also create the second array and set all its elements to 0:

```
int* secondArray = new int[secondSize];
memset(secondArray, 0, sizeof(int) * secondSize);
```

And then you just copy the first array in the first elements of the second:

```
for(int j = 0; j < firstSize; ++j)
{
    secondArray[j] = firstArray[j]; // Set second array equal to first array
}
```

This assuming that secondSize is always bigger than firstSize.